# Java 8, Stream API, Generics что я упустил?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Stream<Object> stream = list.stream();
// маппинг так для примера
List<String> collect = stream.map(obj -> obj.toString()) 
        .collect(toList());
```

Что я упустил в дженериках? Эта конструкция валидна, но убирая дженерик у стрима `Stream stream = list.stream();` уже не валидна?

Или же так, зачем это кастование? `(List<Object>) list`

```
List<String> collect = ((List<Object>) list).stream.map(obj -> obj.toString()) 
            .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214692/why-does-this-java-8-stream-operation-evaluate-to-object-instead-of-listobject), но так как это StackOverflow на русском, приведу перевод:

`stream()`, `map()`, `collect()` и все другие stream методы завязаны на дженериках. Если опустить их использование, то все сопутствующие дженерики в библиотеках также будут опущены и все структуры превратятся в обычные интерфейсы без указания типа. К примеру, если вы используете `List<String>`, то вызвав метод `stream()`, получите `Stream<String>`.

Однако если вы вызовите `stream()` у объекта с типом `List` без указания типа, то вернётся объект `Stream`.

Метод `map()` в этом же случае имеет следующее объявление:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

Но если учитывать тот факт, что тип не был указан, он будет приведён к виду:

```
Stream map(Function mapper)
```

Таким образом, в результате `map()` вернёт объект `Stream`. Что также помешает правильно отработать функции `collect()`, которая из вида:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

Превратится в:

```
 Object collect(Supplier supplier,
                BiConsumer accumulator,
                BiConsumer combiner)
```

Тем самым теряется объявление `List` и `List<String>` соответственно. Что и вызывает ошибку компиляции.

В итоге можно привести данный объект к необходимому виду, однако данный вид приведения вызовет предупреждение `unchecked casts`, так как компилятор не знает, правильно ли вы привели тип.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Stream stream`, то [generics-и пропадают](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) во всех методах `Stream`, и метод `collect` в частности начинает возвращать просто `Object`. При желании, конечно, можно привести результат выполнения метода `collect` к `List<String>`:

```
List<String> collect = (List<String>)stream.map(obj -> obj.toString()) 
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Аналогично с приведением списка к `List<Object>`: либо итоговый `Stream` будет параметризованным, либо окажется raw type с той же самой проблемой.